# How can I replace "XX,XXX" with "XX XXX"?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace string like "XX,XXX" with "XX XXX". The string "XX,XXX" is in another string, e.g:

```
"-1299-5,"XXX,XXXX",trft,4,0,10800"
```

The string is fetched from a text file. I want to split the string by ",". But the comma in the substring led to the wrong result.

The X represents a char. I think regex can help, who can give me the right regex expression.

Comment: replace comma `,` with a space ?

Comment: `"XX,XXX".Replace(',', ' ')`

Comment: For simple replace you can use string method. Eg `"text,text".Replace(',',' ');`

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. You shouldn't blindly split by ",", but properly parse the string to check for commas inside quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression,

```
(.*"[^,]*),([^,]*".*)
```

with a replacement of `$1 $2` might work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Td660j/1/)

#### Example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(.*""[^,]*),([^,]*"".*)";
        string substitution = @"\1 \2";
        string input = @"-1299-5,""XXX,XXXX"",trft,4,0,10800";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply, use 'Replace' to replace char from your string.

```
 var test = "XXX,XXXX";
 var filtered = test.Replace(',', ' ');  
 Console.WriteLine(filtered);
```

Output :

```
XXX XXXX
```